# How to JOIN 2 arrays with different key values in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna write a cool function to preview a PDF file before store it into my hard drive. The problem is: i have 2 arrays. The first table has users input data and the second table has the description of the service. For example:
1st table has the key values:
**ID  NAME LASTNAME SERVICE_ID**
2nd table has only 1 key value:
**SERVICE_DESCRIPTION**
My question is: Can i combine the values into 1 array, so that i have 3rd array with these key values:
**ID  NAME LASTNAME SERVICE_ID SERVICE_DESCRIPTION**
?
Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: How can you store 'SERVICE_DESCRIPTION' in a table without its id?

Comment: You can run a join query, anyway.

Comment: the problem is that the data of array 1 are NOT in the database. But the data of the array 2 are in the database. If both was into the database then the join method is the best way ...

Comment: I think, you are getting it wrongly, what ever its , you can not save any service description in a data base without a distinct id. add a column id . then you can merge it with array or whatever you want to do

Comment: You can merge two arrays with this function, [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can merge two arrays with this function, [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 2):

as @inzamam suggested you can do

```
$a = ["ID NAME" => "some val", "LASTNAME" => "some val", "SERVICE_ID" => "some val"];
$b = ["SERVICE_DESCRIPTION " => "some val"];
$c = array_merge($a,$b); // you can merge multiple arrays as you want
```